# How to return two separate values from an AJAX request?

Tags: php

I have this site that has a countdown. Once the time is 0, I use an AJAX request from JS to then use PHP to update a new countdown and contest. In the new AJAX request, I need to return back two values: the image url and the count_down time.

```
$.ajax({url: "new_contest.php", success: function(result) {
    $("#count_down).time(result); 
});
```

I can return the results with the success function, but then I can only return one of the results. I've also tried creating a `session` in PHP from the AJAX page and then putting a session inside a JS variable. But the process is super complicated and I feel like there is a more easy way to accomplish this...

I don't see a big need to show my code for `new_contest.php` (AJAX page), all the code on that page works towards outputting those two needed values :)

Comment: The most populsr solution is use json.

Comment: @u_mulder Would you mind providing an example? I don't think I've ever used json...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$var = array('time' => "2017-12-23 23:23:23",'someval' => 'hello');
print_r(json_encode($var));
```

in ajax

```
$.post('1.php',{val: 'val'}).done(function(data){
    if(data!='null' && typeof data !=='undefined'){

     data = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#count_down").time(data.time);
      $("#count_up").time(data.someval);    
    }
 })
```

Comment: Ok dumb question, but from the AJAX page. Does the `time` and `someval` represent variables that are echoed from the AJAX page that this page is now loading the result...

Comment: @user6902601 sorry bro i forgo t. thanks for not downvoting updated my answer.. it all array elements from php

Comment: happy to see your comment

Answer (score 1):

If you put the results of your PHP function in an array, you can return that as JSON to the front end using json_encode($yourArray);.

The JSON can be accessed in your AJAX success call much like a PHP array. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/

Answer (score 0):

You should use json if you want to pull out multiple values from a php file...

in your html file...

```
 <script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "yourphpfile.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var thisvariable = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        yourfunction(thisvariable); //do somthing here for the returned json object
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();



</script>
```

then inyour php file

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? This is more of a comment than an answer :)